# How to manually approve a token for swap on Uniswap (direct contract interaction)

Tags: contract-invocation, etherscan, uniswap

I want to approve token spending on Uniswap for a token I don't own. Uniswap UI won't let me do that (instead it displays a gray out button "insufficient balance").

Seems the only option would be to manually approve the token using Etherscan.

Which Uniswap contract should I interact with? (v2)
What are the required parameters and what is the uint for infinite approval?

Comment: You want to approve before getting the token? why not just do it once you have it?

Comment: Because i need to dump it as fast as possible once i have it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **Get the pool address**

Go to the Uniswap UI at https://app.uniswap.org/. Choose the token pair you want and then click the `View pair analytics ↗`. This will take you to a link like `https://uniswap.info/pair/<poolAddress>`. Note down `poolAddress`.

2. **Approve via Etherscan**

Go to `https://etherscan.io/token/<tokenAddress>#writeContract` where tokenAddress is the one you want to approve. Go to the approve tab and now enter `poolAddress` + amount.

Comment: Thx @markus just a few questions: (1) I want to approve the token for swapping, but still need the pool address right? (2) What value should i give to `amount` should i fill for infinite approval?

Comment: @PmRivière (1) Yeah, what did you think? (2) Go for infinite sure. I think even the Uniswap UI does this.

Comment: Infinite would mean 2^256 - 1.

Comment: Just how do i key in 256^-1? it's a UINT256 expected. That would mean i just key in -1?

Comment: @PmRivière "115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935"

Comment: Uniswap V2 Address is `0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D `

Comment: Does anyone knows how to do it on honeyswap? I cannot find view pair analysis button